# extract only date from current_date + interval data type in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get only date without time in postgres from the following statement:

```
select current_date - date_trunc('day',interval '1 month');
```

But returns me that:

```
2023-02-07 00:00:00
```

What could be going wrong here. I see that `date_trunc` function returns timestamp and intervals cannot be cast to `date` type:

```
select current_date - interval '1 month'::date;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to place the `interval` expression into a closure, and then cast that:

```sql
select (current_date - interval '1 month')::date;  -- 2023-02-07
```

Comment: thanks, does casting always involves placing the expression between parenthesis/closure ?

Comment: @moth You need the parentheses in this case to apply the `::date` cast to the entire expression.  In the case of `current_timestamp::date`, you don't need parentheses.